# PHP CodeIgniter Session Library - What BAD things could happen with LONG "sess_time_to_update"?

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, paypal

I have a CI app that takes orders online. I link each order to a session ID b/c anyone can order w/o logging in.

When the user clicks on check out, the session ID is sent to PayPal... in which case, the session ID sent back to me along with payment info.

Sometimes PayPal IPN (instant payment notification) gets delayed.. up to 24 hours. (Yes, not very "instant"). In which case, the session variables are already gone (i.e what & how many they ordered) since the session library clears it up.

In this case, I am sunk. So I thought about extending the sess_time_to_update to like 3 days...

Is there a downside to doing this? If so, what?

Is there a workaround  that I can implement instead?

Answer (score 2):

Store the session information in a database before sending them off to PayPal then when the IPN hits, have it look into the database to retrieve values. You should never use a session for something that critical and something THAT long.